# Eclipse PHP page display differently inside IDE to in browser

Tags: php, eclipse, browser

When I run my PHP project inside Eclipse, I see this:

[image]

But when I view the same URL in the browser I see the version below. Why is this please? I want the full version with all the assets displayed. Is this an intrinsic limitation to running PHP projects inside an IDE, or is there some setting or something else I need to change to get it working properly?

I'm on Windows 10. Using the Latest Chrome Browser.

[image]

Comment: On Windows, Linux or macOS? Differently to which browser?

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome.

Comment: On Windows the browser widget is based on the Internet Explorer by default. You might try the embedded Chromium, but it is still under development and not yet official released (see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549585#c117)).